# Are there any events associated with resize in svg.resize.js?

Tags: svg.js

I am using svg.resize.js, svg.select.js for selecting and resizing svg elements. Once the resize is done, I want to perform some actions on another element.

Are there any events associated with resize in svg.resize.js like dragstart is associated with draggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resizestart, resizing, resizedone are the events fired respectively on start, during and completion of resize.